# wxpython grid header span multiple columns

Tags: user-interface, datagrid, wxpython

I am using wxpython for GUI development. How can I set the top header span cols below it.
For example like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not supported by the grid control. You may be able to use the XLSGrid control found in wxPython 2.9+ though. It is completely owner-drawn, so it should be much more flexible:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.agw.xlsgrid.XLSGrid.html